# Removing multiple child elements from XML

Tags: xml, powershell

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Root>
  <Book>
    <Name>Title1</Name>
    <Name>Title2</Name>
    <Name>Title3</Name>
    <Name>Title3</Name>
    <Name>Title3</Name>
  </Book>
</Root>
```

I would like to delete few selected Name elements from Book node. I tried following approach but doesn't seem to work. What would be the right way to delete the child node using given array (ex. `$delnode`)?

```
$delnode = 'Title1','Title2'
$xml.Root.Book | ? {$delnode -eq $_.Name} | % {$xml.Root.Book.RemoveChild($_)}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `|? {$delnode -contains $_.Name}`

Comment: I had tried using -contains instead of -eq but still doesn't work.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$delnode = @('Title1','Title2')
($xml.Root.Book.ChildNodes | ? {$delnode -eq $_.InnerText}) | % {
    $xml.Root.Book.RemoveChild($_) | Out-Null
}
```

A couple of notes:

- You want to iterate over the `ChildNodes` of the **$xml.Root.Book** element.
- Those child nodes do not have a property named "Name."  They are elements, so they have `InnerText` properties.
- `RemoveChild()` returns the element removed.  Since you don't want this element showing up in your output, the call to `RemoveChild()` gets piped to `Out-Null`.
- Note the parentheses that surround the `ChildNodes` and `?` calls, before the **For-Each** (`%`) call.  These are needed because you do not want to call `RemoveChild()` on a collection you are currently iterating.

Comment: James, it worked beautifully. Really appreciate your effort and passion for not just providing the solution but also explaining about key elements of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

- You need to enumerate the ChildNodes collection of book
- You are comparing the wrong element property. You need to compare based on the text value not the element name (which returns "Name")
- You should use -contains to check if the current node is in the array of items to delete

```
    $delnode = 'Title1','Title2'
    $xml.Root.Book.ChildNodes | ? { $delnode -contains $_.'#text'} | %  {
        $xml.Root.Book.RemoveChild($_)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My first rule when the pipeline gives me trouble, and things aren't working is to stop using the pipeline, refactor code into parts, and use the ISE to debug with breakpoints on intermediate variables to not only debug, but to discover what properties each object has (like `#text`, or `InnerChild`, etc).

This does something very similar to what JamesQMurphy gives as answer, but might also lead to code that is more easily understood, changed, and/or debug.

```
[xml]$xml = (Get-Content D:\test\t1.xml)

Write-Output "`nbefore..."
$xml.Root.Book | ft

$delnode = 'Title1','Title2'
$nodesToDelete = @()
foreach ($title in $delnode) {
    $nodesToDelete += $xml.Root.Book.ChildNodes | ? {$_.InnerText -eq $title}
}

Write-Output "`nto delete..."
$nodesToDelete | ft

Write-Output "`ndeleting..."
$nodesToDelete | % {$xml.Root.Book.RemoveChild($_) | Out-Null}

Write-Output "`nafter..."
$xml.Root.Book | ft
```